# Unable to install ‘sf’ R package on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu, rgdal, sf

I'm not able to install `sf` `R` package on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. I tried

```
install.packages("sf")
```

as well as

```
devtools::install_github("r-spatial/sf")
```

after running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev
```

Getting the following error message:

> configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
>
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’

Wonder what is the way to install `sf`?

Comment: does it help to install `libgdal1-dev`?

Comment: Try and run `gdal-config` on the Linux command line. If it doesn't run, it might tell you what package you need for it. If it does run (it should just print a usage message explaining its arguments), something weird is going on and you should maybe log out and in again.... On my system it comes from `libgdal-dev` which you say you've installed but let's see...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me. Using

```
sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev
```

and then

```
devtools::install_github("r-spatial/sf")
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 installing `libgdal-dev` was enough

Comment: Be sure to install `default-libmysqlclient-dev` on Debian first, otherwise `libgdal-dev` installation will fail. If you already have MariaDB installed, it will reroute to `default-libmariadbclient-dev` automatically.

Answer (score 3):

For Arch users make sure you have `gcc-fortran` installed as the dependencies of `sf` require it specially if you are compiling from source.

```
sudo pacman -S gcc-fortran
```

Then make sure you have the following packages installed.

```
sudo pacman -S gdal proj geos
```

Finally `udunits` is not available in the main repos but in AUR repositories.

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/udunits.git
cd udunits/
makepkg -si
```

You may use `yay` if you please.